# Read the file from Angular Material File Select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Material to select a file. Here it is:

```
<label for="uploadPicture" class="upload-file">
    <mat-icon>add_a_photo</mat-icon>
</label>
<input type="file"
       id="uploadPicture"
       class="hidden-input"
       accept="text/kml, .kml"
       (change)="selectFile($event.target.files[0])">

<button mat-button (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
<button mat-button (click)="onOk()" [disabled]="!selected">Ok</button>
```

This seems to be working fine and my 'selectFile' method is getting called properly.

The problem is, now what? I need to read this file and parse it as an XML file.

This is an instance of a Typescript File object. Here is the definition in lib.dom.d.ts

```
interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModifiedDate: any;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly webkitRelativePath: string;
}
```

I have tried finding documentation for this class, but can't seem to find it. If there's a typescript definition of a file, shouldn't there be a typescript way to read it? Everything uses node or javascript.

Update:

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
let text: string;
fileReader.onload = e => {
  text = fileReader.result;
  console.log('result', text);
};
fileReader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: To the downvoter: What's wrong with this question, please?

Comment: Looking at this: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/9735g2/angular_6_typescript_read_content_from_file_in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add `#fileInput` to the HTML input element in the template.

   `<input #fileInput ...`
2. In your component, declare a reference to the HTML input element, using `@ViewCild`.

   ```
   @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInputRef: ElementRef;
   ```
3. Create a change listener on the HTML input element. It will invoke the `loadDataFile` method when the user selects a file.

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
       const fileInput: HTMLInputElement = this.fileInputRef.nativeElement;
       this.fileInputRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', c => 
       this.loadDataFile(fileInput.files[0]));
   }
   ```
4. Implement the `loadDataFile` method that actually loads the data from the file.

   ```
   loadDataFile(file: File): void {  
       const fileReader= new FileReader();
       fileReader.onload = e => {
           // do something with fileReader.result, that contains the data
       };
       fileReader.readAsText(filename); 
   }
   ```

Comment: I made some changes. See My question for more details.

Comment: I see that you're trying to load a text file, I misinterpreted because of the id="uploadPicture". You're right to rather use fileReader.readAsText(filename). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Hadn't changed that yet. Sorry for the misdirection.